# load txt dataset into matlab in a matrix structure

Tags: matlab, dataset

I need to read a txt dataset and do some analytics by matlab. the structure of the txt file is like this:

ID Genre AgeScale
1  M  20-26

2  F  18-25

So, I want to load this txt file and build a matrix. I was wondering if someone could help me with this. I used fopen function but it gives me a single array not a matrix with 3 columns.

Comment: Have you tried the [`readtable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB has an interactive data importer. Just type uiimport in the command window. It allows you to:

- Name the variable based on heading as shown in your example. You can also manually change them.
- Specify variable (column) type, e.g. numeric, cell array of strings, etc.
- Auto generate an import script for next use (if desired)

If it works for you then congratulations, you don't need to waste hours to write an data import script :)

Comment: You are  a king. Thank you so much dear XMO.

Comment: You are very welcome :)  In case you feel your problem is solved, you can mark this answer accepted.  This is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Function fopen only returns the file ID and not the content of the file. Once you open the file you use the file ID to read line by line and then parse each line with *strsplit* using space as the delimiter.

Here's one simple way of doing so:

```
fid = fopen('textfile.txt');

tline = fgetl(fid);
n = 1;
while ischar(tline)        
    data(n,:) = strsplit(tline(1:end-1),' ');
    n=n+1;
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

Keep in mind that the matrix *data* is type string and not numeric, so if you want to use the numeric values of your dataset, you'll need to take a look at the functions *str2num* (*str2double* in newer versions) and *strtok* to split the AgeScale strings with delimiter '-'.